# Should I pass an object into a constructor (if yes, how to handle tests ?)

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, tdd

Let's suppose I have a "HamburgerCooker" that is supposed to cook a burger, and which is constructed with a "Request" class.

Let's say a "Request" object is constructed with a bunch of informations, and returns a bunch of variables necessary to cook a hamburger.

Hence we have this code :

```
class Request(self, foo1, foo2):
    
    def __init__(self, foo1, foo2):
        initialize_foo()

    def return_something():
        return_foo_processed()

class HamburgerCooker:

    def __init__(self, request):
    """
    Initialize some attributes with some "request" public methods
    """

    def make_burger():
    """
    Use some private attributes and return a burger
    """
```

As you can see, make_burger() is dependant on the good implementation of the request class : if request class does not work properly, make_burger() won't return an expected result even if it is correctly implemented.

So how could I test this ? I would like to avoid using a mock library, so I see several solution :

- Use some raw datas (strings, ints...) in the HamburgerCooker constructor, OR directly in the parameters of the make_burger method but I feel like it does not respect OOP best practices
- Add a setter in the HamburgerCooker that will be used only for mocking
- Consider that the couple request / hamburger are a same unit, and that it is okay if they are tested together.

What would be the best option ?

P.S : sorry If I wrote some mistakes, English is not my native language + this code is a methaphorical exemple that's why it might not be 100% correct, it won't be executed anywhere

P.S 2 : I tend to avoid mocking solutions as my apprenticeship dev environment is extremely secured, and we work with Python 2.X

Comment: I'm wondering why you would like to avoid mocking ? I mean, in your case, passing mocked objects to your `HamburgerCooker` constructor is the proper way to test your code. Mocks allow you to completely control each input of your test, so that only your `HamburgerCooker` is tested and the test result does not depend on the correct/incorrect implementation of Request.

Comment: @Origine Thanks, actually it seems like the perfect solution. Unfortunately, where I work for my apprenticeship, we use Python 2.X and I am not sure to be able to install some external packages. I could maybe mock with some interface classes ?

Comment: Python 2.x comes with a unit testing package (unittest) with a mocking module `unittest.mock`. You can find more information about its usage here : https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/unittest.mock.html

Unfortunately, I don't have Python 2.x on my computer to write an example, but you can find plenty of good tutorials about this on Internet.

And, since you're in an aprenticeship, I guess you could ask someone with more experience from your company to help you with that :)

Answer (score 1):

> Design is what we do to get more of what we want than we would get by just doing it. -- Ruth Malan.

What you are really asking here is a design question - the *machine* doesn't particularly care which of these options you choose.

The answer to any "design" question is going to be "it depends", specifically that it depends on what the "more of what you want" is.

The unspoken assumption of TDD is: if the "more of what you want" is "it should be easy to test", then you will *also* get a bunch of other "more of what you want", for free.

So the broad rule is "do what makes it easier to test".  Often that will mean breaking down an idea into smaller parts, just to make testing easier.

One common pattern would be to distinguish *initializing* an object, from using one object to create another.  In python, that would often manifest as an `__init__` method that is really simple (it initializes data members and nothing else), and one or more "factory methods" that copy data out of other data structures and pass that data to `__init__`.

---

I would expect, based on the information here, that the `Request` component and the `HamburgerCooker` component to be different things that change for different reasons.

The factory method that extracts information from `Request` and passes it to `HamburgerCooker.__init__` is clearly going to be coupled to those two components.  And that's *fine*.  "Unit tests" are a testing strategy, but they aren't the *only* testing strategy.  Allow yourself to tests compositions of multiple components when it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a mocking library to be able to mock. In most cases you can just mock what you need yourself. The libraries just make it easier. Create a MockRequest class that inherits Request and fake everything in there by overriding all methods and returning mocked values.